# Заголовки причин отклонения правок не переведены

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, отклонённые-правки

Заголовки причин отклонения правок не переведены.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В основном у оригинальных строк просто первая буква стала прописной из-за этого переводы сбросились. Подправил.

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16057
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16028
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16070
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16030
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16055
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15989
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15988
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16056

Переводы будут на сайте в новых версиях. Текущая rev 2021.3.1.38676